# how to publish image from android application to facebook api?

Tags: java, android, facebook, post

I  got access token and I add facebook in my android application.I don't know How to publish image from my application to facebook api.
Thanks in Advance
I reffered this link[facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android)

kindly help me how to publish image from android application to facebook api

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have already downloaded the facebook api for android,

//Create a Facebook object,

```
Facbook mfacebook = new Facebook(<your app id>)
```

// Read your image as bytes and store in a byteArray, imgData

// Create a bundle with params,

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
params.putByteArray("picture", imgData);

mfacebook.request(null, params, "POST");
```

You can also do this request asynchronously, using the 'AsyncFacebookRunner' class.